# Go-back-n ARQ why it send again duplicate frame?

Tags: algorithm, networking, udp

Why Go-Back-N ARQ send again duplicate frame? Advantage and disadvantage of this?

Answer (score 1):

So let's look at an example and understand this [image]

so in the image you can see the window size is 4, now you start sending all the packets from 1 to 4 and in between 2 is not reached so after the window size is reached and now the sender sees ACK for packet 2 is not there so it again starts the transmission process from 2 to 4 and therefore the receiver receives duplicate packets for 3 and 4 but receiver discards them.
To understand more - you can view this link [Go back N wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go-Back-N_ARQ).

Comment: i know that but i don't know why duplicate it?

Comment: ok so your doubt is like, instead of not duplicating the other acknowledged packets just send the packet which is not received right ?

Comment: right zenwraight (y) My teacher asks me this question and i can't find the answer :((

Comment: Hi Hoang, so according to my understanding because algorithm of Go-back-n ARQ works like this that's why retransmission happens and so to avoid the duplicate frame another implementation came into existence to overcome this -  Selective Repeat ARQ  ... now this is only my view ....Go back N ARQ came into existence because at that time it was very essential to implement something better that stop and wait and so go back n was implemented...

Answer (score 1):

Because receiver discards all of the out of order packets without at least buffering them go back n arq needs to send same packet set again following from the last acknowledged packet with highest sequence number.

Go back n arq is fast when considering with the stop and wait arq but there are disadvantages like sending same packet multiple times. That's why selective repeat come in to picture. In selective repeat not need send already sent packets again beacause receiver is buffering them.Which means receiver accepts out of order packets.Sender only retransmits packets which acknoweledgements not received. So lost/corrupted packets will retransmitted alone in there.The size of the sending and reciving windows must be equal and half of the sequence number in that case.